# Number of distinct shadow transforms

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, number-theory

### Background

[**Shadow transform**](https://oeis.org/wiki/Shadow_transform) of a 0-based integer sequence \$a(n)\$ is another 0-based integer sequence \$s(n)\$ defined with the following equation:

$$
s(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{(1 \text{ if } n \text{ divides } a(i), 0 \text{ otherwise})}
$$

i.e. \$s(n)\$ is the number of terms in \$a(0), \cdots, a(n-1)\$ that are divisible by \$n\$.

\$s(0)\$ is always 0 because there are zero terms to consider, and \$s(1)\$ is always 1 because \$a(0)\$ is always divisible by 1. \$s(2)\$ may have a value of 0, 1, or 2, depending on how many terms out of \$a(0)\$ and \$a(1)\$ are even.

### Challenge

Given a non-negative integer \$n\$, compute the number of distinct shadow transforms of length \$n\$. This sequence is [A226443](http://oeis.org/A226443).

The following is the list of first 11 terms for \$n = 0, \cdots, 10\$, as listed on the OEIS page.

```
1, 1, 1, 3, 12, 48, 288, 1356, 10848, 70896, 588480
```

**Explanation:** Let's call this sequence \$f(n)\$.

- \$f(0)\$ counts the number of empty sequences, which is 1 (since `[]` counts).
- \$f(1)\$ counts the possible number of `[s(0)]` which can only be `[0]`.
- \$f(2)\$ counts `[s(0),s(1)]`s which can only be `[0,1]`.
- Since `s(2)` can take any of 0, 1, or 2 independent of `s(0)` and `s(1)`, \$f(3)\$ is 3.
- `s(3)` is also independent of `s(0)` through `s(2)` (because 3 is relatively prime to 2) and take a value between 0 and 3 inclusive, so \$f(4) = 3 \cdot 4 = 12\$.
- Finding \$f(5)\$ is slightly more complex because `s(4)` is tied with `s(2)`. If `s(4) == 4`, all of `a(0)..a(3)` must be divisible by 4 (and therefore even), and `s(2)` can only be 2. If `s(4) == 3`, at least one of `a(0)` or `a(1)` must be even, and `s(2)` must be 1 or 2. Therefore, \$f(5) = 12 + 12 + 12 + 8 + 4 = 48\$.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) I/O does NOT apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: It is easy to generate all arrays with \$ n \$ elements each element in \$ 0 \dots \text{LCM}\left(1,\dots,n\right) \$ (to golf more bytes, I would choice \$1\dots n^n\$ instead), apply \$s\$ to it, and then count how many distinct results in all. But I don't know how to test it as it will not produce output in reasonable time even for \$n = 5\$.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

Thanks to [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs) for the fix.

```
%Lċ0
*ṗ’ÇƤ€QL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//JUzEizAKKuG5l@KAmcOHxqTigqxRTP///zM)

The first line computes the shadow transform.

The second line looks at the shadow transform of all sequences of length `n` with elements in `{1, 2, ..., n^n}`.

Comment: You're currently off by one, \$f(3)\$ should be \$3\$. `µ` -> `’` would fix this at the cost of a bit of effiency.

Comment: @ovs fixed, thanks.

Comment: You can group the helper link with `Ʋ` and save a byte - `*ṗ’%Lċ0ƲƤ€QL`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), <s>228</s> 225 bytes

This is based on the first PARI implementation on OEIS and computes terms up to \$n=6\$ on TIO.

```python
import math,itertools as I
L=math.log
R=range
n=input()
P=k=r=1
while k<n:k+=1;r*=k**int(P%k*L(n+.5)/L(k));P*=k*k
print len({tuple(sum(x%o<1for x in s[:o])for o in R(n))for s in I.product(*[[i+1for i in R(r)if-1<r%~i]]*~-n)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY9Pa4MwGMbv76cIgpDE6Wa37mDNByh4kLKbeJA2rSGahNfIlLF@dbe0x9/zDx63@t6aXepWt27fvRok@cJZFkQu8kyiKNrU6Cx6Mna@f1Feord2mEg3kSNUIqjZYG9wEtiZmwQjlHGzpwxqoQWKHJ6jujSFTkR@QC4058p4WseaV9Qk2Z69VlQzdqiDp8Hhv00GaeiPn90g6TSPdIltmV8tkoUoQ6amsC0LaAOeqGEPmgIdM4f2Mp895U2jkkdLPWPI1DXNS4zvqm35PTXsl23h5RvksIN3@IA9fP4B)

---

Naive bruteforcing is obviously a lot shorter (100 bytes):

```python
lambda n,R=range:len({tuple(sum(s/n**(n*x)%n**n%o<1for x in R(o))for o in R(n))for s in R(n**n**2)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc3BCsIwEATQu1@xl9LdEBELXor1I3r2EjHRQLoJSQoV8dtjY73NGwYmvPLTc1fMcC1OTbe7ApbjEBU/dO804zvPwWlM84TpwEIgi4WaNXDjz0fjIyxgGUb0RFV@E29Kf61zITr6UKmtre3vAk/U7wBCtJzBSmj3l1aCQUvlCw) Crashes for \$n=4\$ with a *MemoryError*, when `R(n**n**2)` tries to create a list of \$2^{32}\$ integers.